Prevent saving Entity Framework Core entities when string is exceeding the DB column length
I have a big dictionary (with over 1k entries) defined like this:
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
   ...
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Savings_Rate, L.GrowthProposedSavingsRate.ToString("0.00") },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Income_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedIncomeGrowthRate.ToString() },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Portfolio_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedPortfolioGrowthRate.ToString() },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedFMVRealEstateGrowthRate.ToString() },
    ...
}     

And the constants are defined like this:
 public const string Growth_Proposed_Savings_Rate = "Growth_Proposed_Savings_Rate";
 public const string Growth_Proposed_Income_Growth_Rate = "Growth_Proposed_Income_Growth_Rate";
 public const string Growth_Proposed_Portfolio_Growth_Rate = "Growth_Proposed_Portfolio_Growth_Rate";
 public const string Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate = "Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate";

This dictionary is saved in a SQL database in some columns where the datatype is set to nvarchar(50) for each. I have situations when because of refactoring (to give a meaningful description) the value of a constant is changed in something longer than 50 chars like Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate to Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate_from_2023_2024_First_Quater.
When this change is performed the developer is not aware that this modification will crash the system at some point when this string will be inserted into the database.
For now I put this code just to crash fast and detect such cases at the first run:
 foreach (var item in dic)
 if (item.Key.Length > 50)
     throw new Exception($"{item.Key} is over 50 chars and will throw an exception on DB save.");

My question is: can I prevent such situations at the compile time with some attributes? or any other valid solution to avoid this workaround?

Low effort version: put a comment near the constants? Med effort version: Write a VS extension that looks for a class attribute defining the max len and checks the string constants within to see if any go over the states limit. If you do it as a package to the assembly it "auto installs". If you're backing your test contexts by a real db or a suitably intelligent mock, you could also create a unit test that reflectively applies and saves every constant present in the constants class

@flackoverstow - "put a comment near the constants" is not working because they do it with "Quick Action and Refactoring" or "Rename" from the menu... These constants are used in many many places in code. And about writing a VS extension I think is to much and force everyone to install it and use it just for such a case.

Analyzers can be a part of the solution, like a nuget package, so people don't install it per se.. But if you did go the installed extension route it really only needs one developer to do it, then they can nag the others. Do you have a PR process this can go in? How about writing a static initializer that reflectively checks all the lengths and throws an exception? It only runs once.. If you really want some minimum effort solution; just make the DB column longer - it's not going to impact much til you can get around to running a query that looks for too-long values and refactor

Instead of storing the text string in the db, you could use an integer as the key. Use an enum to map your text strings into the integers, and specify the transformation in the EF model. Then the enum text can be anything you want and the db is always protected.

@pjs... can't do... those strings (keys) are mapped in some templates and will be replaced with values.... and if they are numbers it will be very hard to read those templates and understand  what should have been there.

At compile time there really isn't any option outside of running an external validation add-in/tool. Keep in mind that an external validation will work for things like generated constants, but not runtime assignments from variable strings. At runtime you can integrate the fixed length check into a custom type that asserts its length:
public abstract class StringN(string value, uint length)
{
    public string Value { get; } = value.LengthChecked(length);

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringN value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}

public sealed class String50(string value) : StringN(value, Length)
{
    public const uint Length = 50;
    public static implicit operator String50(string value)
    {
        return new String50(value);
    }
}

public static class FixedLengthStringExtensions
{
    public static string LengthChecked(this string value, uint length)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length > length)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Length of fixed string exceeded. '{value}' {value.Length}/{length}");

        return value;
    }
}

This will validate and throw at runtime when the dictionary or any other use of a String{N} is used. In your case the only change would be in the declaration:
Dictionary<String50, string> dic = new Dictionary<String50, string>
{
   ...
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Savings_Rate, L.GrowthProposedSavingsRate.ToString("0.00") },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Income_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedIncomeGrowthRate.ToString() },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_Portfolio_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedPortfolioGrowthRate.ToString() },
   { PlanVariablesDefinitions.Growth_Proposed_FMVRealEstate_Growth_Rate, L.GrowthProposedFMVRealEstateGrowthRate.ToString() },
    ...
}

It's pretty compact. I opted for the length validation as an extension method which I think tied quite nicely into the primary constructor initialization.
No need to write a pre-validation loop, and it can catch any situations at runtime when a fixed-length value is re-assigned. You do need to declare a class for each/any fixed length string length you want to use, but these are dead simple with just the name update and the constant length. Assignment to and from string is implemented and ready to go.
Inspiration from this answer: String Object with fixed length C#

Yup, it's smart and I like it.
